# Issue with EF IdentityDbContext when using async Methods

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

why does the following code always produce an "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending"?

When I use 'Dim OriginalUser As ApplicationUser = db.Users.Where(Function(p) p.Id = id).ToList(0)' it works fine.

Lazy Loading is disabled on the ApplicationDBContext which inherits from IdentityDbContext. Why isn't the Context available anymore for the SaveChanges-Part? What am I missing?

```
    Public Async Sub PatchUser(id As String, <FromBody> ChangedUserAttributes As Delta(Of ApplicationUser))
    Using ctx As New ApplicationDbContext
        Validate(ChangedUserAttributes.GetEntity())

        If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
            Throw New HttpResponseException(New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest))
        End If

        Dim OriginalUser As ApplicationUser = Await ctx.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(Function(p) p.Id = id)
        If OriginalUser Is Nothing Then
            Throw New HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        End If

        Try
            ChangedUserAttributes.TrySetPropertyValue("Email", "Emil") 
            ChangedUserAttributes.Patch(OriginalUser)
            Await ctx.SaveChangesAsync
            Return
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New HttpResponseException(New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest))
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `Async Sub`. This method should be an asynchronous function returning `Task`, and (if you call it yourself) it would need to be called with `Await`.

You may find my article on [`async` on ASP.NET helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx):

> When an asynchronous handler completes the request, but ASP.NET detects asynchronous work that hasn’t completed, you get an Invalid­OperationException with the message, “An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.” This is usually due to asynchronous code calling an async void method

As well as my article on [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx):

> Avoid async void... Async methods returning void don’t provide an easy way to notify the calling code that they’ve completed. It’s easy to start several async void methods, but it’s not easy to determine when they’ve finished.

Comment: It looks like it's a controller action so it wouldn't be called directly, but you're certainly right about it being `Async Function ... As Task` rather than `Async Sub`.

Comment: Thanks, that already helped. I used a Sub because on a PATCH action in WEB API the result should be a 204 (No content) according to Microsoft (https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results). But when I try to return Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent) I get an 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult' error.

Comment: @user3767106: You should be returning just a plain `Task`, not task *of* anything.

Comment: But then I am not able to set the correct HTTP status code in case of an error.

Comment: @user3767106: Throw an [`HttpException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx).